# Python autocomplete user input

Tags: python, string, printing, autocomplete, sentence

I have a list of teamnames. Let's say they are

```
teamnames=["Blackpool","Blackburn","Arsenal"]
```

In the program I ask the user which team he would like to do stuff with. I want python to autocomplete the user's input if it matches a team and print it.

So if the user writes "Bla" and presses <kbd>enter</kbd>, the team Blackburn should automatically be printed in that space and used in the rest of the code. So for example;

Your choice: Bla (User writes "Bla" and presses <kbd>enter</kbd>)

*What it should look like*

Your Choice: Blackburn (The program finishes the rest of the word)

Comment: So what have you tried till now, you should include that too. Let us see your efforts till now. Where are you stuck exactly in your code.

Comment: Why is this question off topic? it seems to clearly ask for how to implement "enter"-completion (like tab-completion) in python given a list of possible inputs.

Comment: it is not off topic, it simply doesn't show any effort.

Answer (score 1):

```
teamnames=["Blackpool","Blackburn","Arsenal"]

user_input = raw_input("Your choice: ")

# You have to handle the case where 2 or more teams starts with the same string.
# For example the user input is 'B'. So you have to select between "Blackpool" and
# "Blackburn"
filtered_teams = filter(lambda x: x.startswith(user_input), teamnames)

if len(filtered_teams) > 1:
    # Deal with more that one team.
    print('There are more than one team starting with "{0}"'.format(user_input))
    print('Select the team from choices: ')
    for index, name in enumerate(filtered_teams):
        print("{0}: {1}".format(index, name))

    index = input("Enter choice number: ")
    # You might want to handle IndexError exception here.
    print('Selected team: {0}'.format(filtered_teams[index]))

else:
    # Only one team found, so print that team.
    print filtered_teams[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your usecase. If your program is commandline based, you can do that at least by using the [readline](http://doughellmann.com/2008/11/pymotw-readline.html) module and pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd>. This link also provides some well explained examples on that since its Doug Hellmanns PyMOTW. If you are trying that via a GUI it depends on the API you are using. In that case you need to deliver some more details please.