# enable auto-completion in Python input prompt

Tags: python, input, autocomplete

Is there a way to, using the modules `cmd` or `readline`, get smart completion when reading an input string that only matches a specific set of values?

For instance:

```
read_from_list(prompt"Name:", allowed_values=["Adam", "Bert", "Cesar"])
```

will create prompt

```
Name:
```

If I enter

```
Ad
```

and press complete (typically via Tab-key) I get

```
Adam
```

As a bonus it shouldn't even be possible to enter a string other than `Adam`, `Bert` or `Cesar` together with a set of all their prefixes.

Update: In essence I want a Python 3 variant of Emacs's `completing-read`: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Minibuffer-Completion.html

Comment: I found this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20972367/8069403